# How do I use $save() in Firebase' Angular-Fire to Update Object Property Values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have the code below:

```
var FBref = new Firebase('https://employees.firebaseio.com/');
var peopleObject = $firebaseArray(FBref);

var person = {  
            "name":"John",
            "age":"20",
            "phone":"123-123-123"
        };

peopleObject.$add(person);
```

I use the code above to add new records of employees successfully.

I need to update the John's phone number to 111-111-111. But the code below doesn't work.

```
var person = {  
            "name":"John",
            "age":"20",
            "phone":"111-111-111" //New phone number
        };

peopleObject.$save(person);
```

Someone advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are trying to save whole object, which wouldn't work.

Retrieve old record first by getting record from db first & then update that record. Thereafter save that object using `$save` method.

```
//if update action is happening is similar session you can get unique by below code
var someRecordKey; 
peopleObject.$add(person).then(function(ref) { 
    //get record id of new person 
    someRecordKey = ref.key(); 
});

// get record by unique key
var person = peopleObject.$getRecord(someRecordKey);
// change a message and save it
item.phone = "111-111-111";
peopleObject.$save(person).then(function() {
    // data has been saved to our database
});
```

Comment: You can get someRecordKey with the following code `var someRecordKey;
peopleObject.$add(person).then(function(ref) {
    //get record id of new person
    someRecordKey = ref.key();
});`

Comment: @huseyinozcan yes.. we can.. but I'm considering that..this thing can be happen in different session.. isn't it? Thanks for heads up.. I updated the answer. :)

Comment: Good point @PankajParkar !  Seems like update action happens in different session

Comment: @PankajParkar. Thank you. However, the record I need to update is not the new record I am adding. It's a record which is already in the database. The key (someRecordKey) is for the new record I'm adding. How can I get the key of a record already in the firebase database?